# SwiftUI Random but unique elements

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I have a simple array of 3 fonts

```
  var fonts = ["Arial", "System", "Helvetica"]
    
  let randomFont: String
```

so the user is asked to guess one of the 3

```
 VStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text("Which font is \(randomFont)?")
```

so this correctly displays one of the 3 elements.

Each has to use a unique element of the fonts array and...if is the same font as per randomFont the counter should be increased by one.

Here is an hardcoded example:

```
        Button(action: { self.score += 1 }) {
            Text("\(randomWord)").font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 40))
        }
        
        Button(action: { self.score += 0 }) {
            Text("\(randomWord)").font(.custom("Arial", size: 40))
        }
        
        Button(action: { self.score += 0 }) {
            Text("\(randomWord)").font(.system(size: 40))
        }
```

I need help to randomise the fonts but all 3 have to be used. Additionally I need to compare the random font selected by the user with the font displayed in the question. if is the same (right answer) a point is added.

so for instance
randomFont is "Arial"
the buttons will display 3 words in a random font (e.g.randomFont2 variable) (Arial, Helvetica or system all have to be used and no duplicates) if the user clicks the button with the Arial font +1 point is added to the counter.

Comment: Array has a `.shuffle()` or `.shuffled()` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete standalone example.  I used 3 very distinct fonts (*Courier*, *System*, and *Papyrus*) for testing purposes.

`fonts.shuffle()` is used to randomize the fonts.

The three buttons only differ in the font index they are using and looking for, so I've used a private function to contruct the buttons to avoid repetition.

The randomly chosen `randomFontIndex` uses `Int.random(in: 0..<3)` to choose a number that is `0`, `1`, or `2`.  To add more fonts, just add more font names to the `fonts` array.  Make sure to select valid font names though!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let words = ["birds", "meadow", "butterfly", "flowers"]
    @State private var randomFontIndex = 0
    @State private var randomFont = "Courier"
    @State private var fonts = ["Courier", "System", "Papyrus"]
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var randomWord = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("Score: \(score)")
            Text("Which font is \(randomFont)?")
            buttonFromNumber(0)
            buttonFromNumber(1)
            buttonFromNumber(2)
        }.onAppear { self.newGame() }
    }
    
    private func fontFromName(name: String) -> Font {
        switch name {
        case "System":
            return Font.system(size: 40)
        default:
            return Font.custom(name, size: 40)
        }
    }
    
    private func buttonFromNumber(_ number: Int) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            if number == self.randomFontIndex {
                self.score += 1
            } else {
                self.score -= 1
            }
            self.newGame()
        }) {
            Text("\(randomWord)").font(fontFromName(name: fonts[number]))
        }
    }
    
    private func newGame() {
        fonts.shuffle()
        randomFontIndex = .random(in: 0..<3)
        randomFont = fonts[randomFontIndex]
        randomWord = words.randomElement()!
    }
}
```